# add Cmder in Rstudio terminal

Tags: terminal, cmder, rstudio

I would like to know how to add Cmder (Portable console emulator for Windows) in Rstudio terminal ? I add this *C:\cmder\vendor\bin* in environment variables but without any effect.

[tools -> global options -> terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Tvh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either ask Rstudio developers implement the ability to run third-party terminals
Or go to the *ConEmu* [Default Terminal](https://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html) feature.